# Modifying the appearance of ghsystem's hazard and precautionary statements

Tags: chemistry

The `ghsystem` package allows to generate hazard and precautionary statements as defined by the CLP Regulation of the EU.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{ghsystem}
\begin{document}
\ghs{p}{302+352} \ghs{p}{210}

\underline{P302+P352}: IF ON SKIN: Wash with plenty of soap and water. \underline{P210}: Keep away from heat/sparks/open flames/hot surfaces. — No smoking.
\end{document}
```

will compile to give:
[image]
I could not identify a method to modify the appearance of the `ghsystem`-generated H and P statements. In particular, I would prefer to not have spaces within the identifier of combined statements (P302+P352) and also have the statement identifier underlined as shown in the second paragraph. Is it possible to configure `ghsystem` to generate the output of the second paragraph using the code in the first paragraph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I could tell from the documentation and the code, options for customization of the space around the `+` in combined statements as well as of the style of the type and number(s) are currently not provided in the `ghsystem` package.

Here is a first rough attempt on adding these options that surely is still in need of improvement.

Using the newly introduced options `plus-space` and `number-style`, (for example as in `\ghssetup{plus-space=, number-style=\uline}`), you can remove the space around the `+` and make sure the letters and numbers identifying the statements are underlined. Since I used `\ulem`'s `\uline` command instead of `\underline`, the output (upper part) looks a little different than the manually created one from your question (lower half):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{ulem} % Needed for the \uline command, that I used instead of \underline
\usepackage{ghsystem}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N   \l__ghsystem_plus_space_tl
\tl_new:N   \l__ghsystem_number_style_tl
\tl_new:N   \l__ghsystem_text_style_tl

\keys_define:nn {ghsystem}
  {
    plus-space                      .tl_set:N   =
      \l__ghsystem_plus_space_tl ,
    plus-space .initial:n = \nobreakspace ,
    number-style                    .tl_set:N   =
      \l__ghsystem_number_style_tl ,
    text-style                      .tl_set:N   =
      \l__ghsystem_text_style_tl ,
    text-style .initial:n = \normalfont,
  }

\cs_set:Npn \__ghsystem_is_combination_aux_i:w #1,#2+#3 \q_stop
  {
    \bool_if:NT \l__ghsystem_show_number_bool
      {
        \tl_use:N \l__ghsystem_number_style_tl{\text_uppercase:n {#1}}
        \tl_use:N \l__ghsystem_number_space_tl
        \tl_use:N \l__ghsystem_number_style_tl{#2 \tl_use:N \l__ghsystem_plus_space_tl + \tl_use:N \l__ghsystem_plus_space_tl}
        \tl_if_in:nnTF {#3} { + }
          { \__ghsystem_is_combination_aux_iii:w #1,#3 \q_stop }
          {
            \tl_use:N \l__ghsystem_number_style_tl{\text_uppercase:n {#1}}
            \tl_use:N \l__ghsystem_number_space_tl
            \tl_use:N \l__ghsystem_number_style_tl{#3} \bool_if:NF \l__ghsystem_hide_statement_bool { \tl_use:N \l__ghsystem_number_style_tl{:} \l__ghsystem_text_style_tl{} ~ }
          }
      }
  }

\cs_set:Npn \__ghsystem_is_combination_aux_ii:w #1,#2 \q_stop
  {
    \bool_if:NT \l__ghsystem_show_number_bool
      {
        \tl_use:N \l__ghsystem_number_style_tl{\text_uppercase:n {#1}}
        \tl_use:N \l__ghsystem_number_space_tl
        \tl_use:N \l__ghsystem_number_style_tl{#2} \bool_if:NF \l__ghsystem_hide_statement_bool { \tl_use:N \l__ghsystem_number_style_tl{:} \l__ghsystem_text_style_tl{} ~ }
      }
  }

\cs_set:Npn \__ghsystem_is_combination_aux_iii:w #1,#2+#3 \q_stop
  {
    \bool_if:NT \l__ghsystem_show_number_bool
      {
        \tl_use:N \l__ghsystem_number_style_tl{\text_uppercase:n {#1}}
        \tl_use:N \l__ghsystem_number_space_tl
        \tl_use:N \l__ghsystem_number_style_tl{#2 \tl_use:N \l__ghsystem_plus_space_tl + \tl_use:N \l__ghsystem_plus_space_tl}
        \tl_use:N \l__ghsystem_number_style_tl{\text_uppercase:n {#1}}
        \tl_use:N \l__ghsystem_number_space_tl
        \tl_use:N \l__ghsystem_number_style_tl{#3} \bool_if:NF \l__ghsystem_hide_statement_bool { \tl_use:N \l__ghsystem_number_style_tl{:} \l__ghsystem_text_style_tl{} ~ }
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\ghssetup{plus-space=, number-style=\uline}
 
\begin{document}
\ghs{p}{302+352} \ghs{p}{210}

\underline{P302+P352}: IF ON SKIN: Wash with plenty of soap and water. \underline{P210}: Keep away from heat/sparks/open flames/hot surfaces. — No smoking.
\end{document}
```

---

Here are some other outputs, than can be obtain with the preamble of the MWE above:

[image]

```
\ghssetup{number-style=\bfseries}
\ghs{p}{302+352} \ghs{p}{210}

\medskip
\ghssetup{number-style=\itshape}
\ghs{p}{302+352} \ghs{p}{210}

\medskip
\ghssetup{number-style=\bfseries\textcolor{red}} % additionally needs `\usepackage{xcolor}
\ghs{p}{302+352} \ghs{p}{210}

\medskip
\ghssetup{number-style=\bfseries\uline, text-style=\normalfont\itshape}
\ghs{p}{302+352} \ghs{p}{210}

\medskip
\ghssetup{number-style=\textit, text-style=\color{blue}} % additionally needs `\usepackage{xcolor}
\ghs{p}{302+352} \ghs{p}{210}
```